# Loop through list of dataframes and save as new dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through a list of dataframes and perform operations on them.  In the final command I want to rename the dataframe as the original key plus `'_rand_test'`.  I'm getting the error:

`SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator`

Is there a way to do this?

```
segments = [main_h, main_m, main_l]
seg_name = ['main_h', 'main_m', 'main_l']

for i in segments:
    control = pd.DataFrame(i.groupby('State', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x : x.sample(frac = .1)))
    control['segment'] = 'control'
    test= i[~i.index.isin(control.index)]
    test['segment'] = 'test'
    seg_name[i]+'_rand_test' = pd.concat([control,test])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to perform addition on the left side of an = sign, which you can never do. If you want to rename the dataframe you could just do it on the next line. I'm unsure of what exactly you're trying to rename based off of the code, but if it's just the corresponding string in the seg_name list then the next line would look like this:

```
seg_name[segments.index(i)] += 'rand_test'
```

The reason for the segments.index(i) is because you're looping over the elements in segments, not their indexes, so you need to get the index of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you?
Create an empty list befor you run the loop and fill that list with append function. And then you rename all the elements of the new list.

```
segments = [main_h, main_m, main_l]
seg_name = ['main_h', 'main_m', 'main_l']
new_list= []

for i in segments:
    control = pd.DataFrame(i.groupby('State', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x : x.sample(frac = .1)))
    control['segment'] = 'control'
    test= i[~i.index.isin(control.index)]
    test['segment'] = 'test'
    new_list.append(df)

new_names_list=[item +'_rand_test' for item in new_list]
```